# Conditional histogram with some factors left out

Tags: r

I managed to plot conditional historgrams using lattice:

```
histogram(~x|y, data=df)
```

y in my case has multiple factors, and I do want histogram just for some of them. I searched the forum, but found just posts about how to plot conditional histograms and nothing about selecting the factors, so thanks for your answers.

Comment: Easier solution: subset your "df" first and plot the resulting data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subset` parameter of `histogram` to select only certain levels of your factor.

For example

```
library(lattice)

histogram(~ Sepal.Width | Species, iris, 
          subset = (Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor")))
```

or

```
histogram(~ Sepal.Width | Species, iris, 
          subset = (Species != "setosa"))
```